# notation meaning in the book "Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, notation, sieve-theory

in p. 73-74 of the book by Tenenbaum I see the following notation to define $a_n$. Could anyone help to understand the notation? thanks.

[image: nota]

Comment: It is called the characteristic function of a set and is 1 iff $n/R\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0$ otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the indicator function that $n/R \in \mathbb{N}$. Formally:
$$
1_{\mathbb{N}}(n/R) = 
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $n/R \in \mathbb{N}$} \\
0, &\text{if $n/R \notin \mathbb{N}$}
\end{cases}
$$